# TCP Socket Winsock echo server code printf only works with a delay inserted

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp, winsock

I'm attempting to get this TCP Socket server code running in order to log incoming data.  However I'm having trouble understanding why the server doesn't properly print the incoming buffer (char buffer) when using printf.  The echo command that I receive back on my telnet client is exactly correct regardless if any delay is inserted.

Here's the code:

```
/*
TCP Echo server example in winsock
Live Server on port 8888
*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include "logText.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

#define DEBUG 0;
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    //SOCKET master, new_socket, client_socket[30], s;
    SOCKET master, new_socket, client_socket[1000], s;
    struct sockaddr_in server, address;
    //int max_clients = 30, activity, addrlen, i, valread;
    int max_clients = 1000; //increased to 1000 connections
    int activity, addrlen, i, j, valread;           
    char *message = "ECHO Daemon v1.0 \r\n";

    //  bool startMessage;

    //size of our receive buffer, this is string length.
    //int MAXRECV = 1024
    int MAXRECV = 1024;
    //set of socket descriptors
    fd_set readfds;
    //1 extra for null character, string termination
    char *buffer;
    char *temp;

//  memset(temp, '\0', sizeof(temp));

    temp = (char*)malloc((MAXRECV + 1) * sizeof(char));
    buffer = (char*)malloc((MAXRECV + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp, buffer);

    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
        //for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        client_socket[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if ((master = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.100.202");
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);

    //Bind
    if (bind(master, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts("Bind done");

    //Listen to incoming connections
    listen(master, 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

    addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while (TRUE)                            //infinite looping for socket hanndling
    {
        //clear the socket fd set
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);

        //add master socket to fd set
        FD_SET(master, &readfds);

        //add child sockets to fd set
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
        {
            s = client_socket[i];
            if (s > 0)
            {
                FD_SET(s, &readfds);
            }
        }

        //wait for an activity on any of the sockets, timeout is NULL , so wait indefinitely
        activity = select(0, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);                               //Select handles the multiple connections

        if (activity == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("select call failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //If something happened on the master socket , then its an incoming connection
        if (FD_ISSET(master, &readfds))
        {
            if ((new_socket = accept(master, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (int *)&addrlen))<0)
            {
                perror("accept");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands
            //printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d \n", new_socket, inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), ntohs(address.sin_port));

            //send new connection greeting message
            if (send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0) != strlen(message))
            {
                perror("send failed");
            }

            //puts("Welcome message sent successfully");

            //add new socket to array of sockets
            for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
            {
                if (client_socket[i] == 0)
                {
                    client_socket[i] = new_socket;
                    printf("Adding to list of sockets at index %d \n", i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //else its some IO operation on some other socket :)
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
        {
            s = client_socket[i];
            //if client presend in read sockets             
            if (FD_ISSET(s, &readfds))
            {
                //get details of the client
                getpeername(s, (struct sockaddr*)&address, (int*)&addrlen);

                //Check if it was for closing , and also read the incoming message
                //recv does not place a null terminator at the end of the string (whilst printf %s assumes there is one).
                valread = recv(s, buffer, MAXRECV, 0);

                if (valread == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    int error_code = WSAGetLastError();
                    if (error_code == WSAECONNRESET)
                    {
                        //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print
                        printf("Host disconnected unexpectedly , ip %s , port %d \n", inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), ntohs(address.sin_port));

                        //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse
                        closesocket(s);
                        client_socket[i] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("recv failed with error code : %d", error_code);
                    }
                }
                if (valread == 0)
                {
                    //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print
                    printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n", inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), ntohs(address.sin_port));

                    //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse
                    closesocket(s);
                    client_socket[i] = 0;
                }

                //Echo back the message that came in
                else
                {
                    //add null character, if you want to use with printf/puts or other string handling functions
                    buffer[valread] = '\0';
                    printf("%s:%d - %s \n", inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), ntohs(address.sin_port), buffer);
                    send(s, buffer, valread, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the server code output after sending a packet file from my telnet client:

```
Initialising Winsock...Initialised.
Socket created.
Bind done
Waiting for incoming connections...
Adding to list of sockets at index 0
192.168.100.202:61776 - aa
 92.168.100.202:61776 - aaaaaaaa
192.168.100.202:61776 - ff
 92.168.100.202:61776 - ffffffff
 92.168.100.202:61776 - hhhh
192.168.100.202:61776 - k
 92.168.100.202:61776 - kkkkkkkkk
 92.168.100.202:61776 - l
 92.168.100.202:61776 - oo
```

The actual file I'm sending is just a text file with fifteen lines:

```
aaaaaaaaaa<CR><LF>
bbbbbbbbbb<CR><LF>
cccccccccc<CR><LF>
dddddddddd<CR><LF>
eeeeeeeeee<CR><LF>
ffffffffff<CR><LF>
gggggggggg<CR><LF>
hhhhhhhhhh<CR><LF>
iiiiiiiiii<CR><LF>
jjjjjjjjjj<CR><LF>
kkkkkkkkkk<CR><LF>
llllllllll<CR><LF>
mmmmmmmmmm<CR><LF>
nnnnnnnnnn<CR><LF>
oooooooooo<CR><LF>
```

When I insert a 100ms delay from my client program, the output is at least all there:

```
Initialising Winsock...Initialised.
Socket created.
Bind done
Waiting for incoming connections...
Adding to list of sockets at index 0

192.168.100.202:61836 - aa
 92.168.100.202:61836 - aaaaaaaa
192.168.100.202:61836 - bbbbbb
 92.168.100.202:61836 - bbbb
192.168.100.202:61836 - cccccccc
 92.168.100.202:61836 - cc
192.168.100.202:61836 - d
 92.168.100.202:61836 - ddddddddd
192.168.100.202:61836 - eeeeeeee
 92.168.100.202:61836 - ee
192.168.100.202:61836 - fff
 92.168.100.202:61836 - fffffff
192.168.100.202:61836 - gggggggg
 92.168.100.202:61836 - gg
192.168.100.202:61836 - hhhhhhh
 92.168.100.202:61836 - hhh
192.168.100.202:61836 - i
 92.168.100.202:61836 - iiiiiiiii
192.168.100.202:61836 - jjjjjjj
 92.168.100.202:61836 - jjj
192.168.100.202:61836 - kkkkkkk
 92.168.100.202:61836 - kkk
192.168.100.202:61836 - llll
 92.168.100.202:61836 - llllll
192.168.100.202:61836 - mm
 92.168.100.202:61836 - mmmmmmmm
192.168.100.202:61836 - n
 92.168.100.202:61836 - nnnnnnnnn
192.168.100.202:61836 - ooooooo
 92.168.100.202:61836 - ooo
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: By default, the standard output is line-buffered.  If you want the data dispatched to that stream to appear immediately on the console then either ensure that a newline is printed at the end or `fflush(stdout)` afterward.  If you're concerned about it in the case that the output is redirected to a file then the `fflush()` alternative is probably better, as in that case the output might well be fully buffered.

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `temp = (char*)malloc((MAXRECV + 1) * sizeof(char));`   1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `malloc()` to assure the operation was successful.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect.  suggest remove that expression. 3) the returned value has type `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: regarding: `strcpy(temp, buffer);` the contents of `buffer` is random trash.  For the call to `strcpy()` to work properly, the `buffer` must contain a '\0' value .  There is no guarantee of such a character being present.  If there is no '\0' in the buffer, then the result is undefined behavior and will result in overrunning the upper bound of the memory pointed to by `temp`

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr` not `stdout`  so this line: `printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());` is outputting the error message to the wrong place

Comment: regarding this line: `activity = select(0, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);`   1) the posted code seems to be missing the statement: `#include <sys/select.>`  2)  the first parameter to `select()` 'nfds' is: the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three  sets, plus 1.  SO 0 is not a valid value

Comment: when the server is waiting for some input from a client, it is better to use `accept()` (waiting for a new client)  and when a new client makes the connection, then pass that socket to a thread to handle

Comment: the contents of `temp` is never used, so all references to `temp` can be eliminated.

Comment: None of the contents of the header file: 'logtext.h' is used in the posted code.

Comment: regarding this, at the end of the program: `closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();`  If the program ever gets there, it is the `master` socket that still needs to be closed.  And the code should loop through the childsocket[] array, to close any sockets that are still open

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`  for `exit()`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, `malloc()`.     the code should also be calling `free()` when preparing to exit the program

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>` for `strlen()`, `strcpy()`

Comment: not sure what `SOCKET` is, but the function `socket()` returns an `int`

Comment: the call to `getpeername()` changes the value in the last parameter, so that needs to be corrected before calling this function.  The function can return: -1 and the code should be checking for that value

Comment: the posted output seems to indicate there is more than one instance of the program running.  Suggest calling `printf()` with the variable `valread` to see the actual number of incoming byte count read.  suggest running just one client instance while debugging the program.  Suggest identifying each echo of the client inflammation etc to include a indication of which program produced that information, including the socket number